# Checking the integrity of a copied folder

Tags: linux, external, integrity

I am copying a big folder (300Gb) into an external hard drive. I want to make sure the copied file is complete and not corrupt before deleting the original file. How can I do that in ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `rsync --checksum` to check the files. Or simply use `sha256sum` or similar to check the files manually. Using `rsync` is in my opinion more comfortable because it automatically checks recursively, but that largely depends on your usecase.

If you really require absolute integrity, you should really consider using an error correction code . Hard drives don't keep data integrity forever, a bit might change from time to time.